# animation bar button for UISegmentedControl is not moving?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, animation, uisegmentedcontrol

I have design Animating the Button Bar UISegmentedControl "showUsers" in Swift and when I tried to implement the animation is not working the bar still hold the first Segment and not moving to the second segment
example https://www.codementor.io/kevinfarst/designing-a-button-bar-style-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift-cg6cf0dok

```
override public func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showUsers.backgroundColor = .clear
    showUsers.tintColor = .clear

    showUsers.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 18),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red:0.44, green:0.44, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
        ], for: .normal)

    showUsers.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 18),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red:0.44, green:0.44, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
        ], for: .selected)

    let buttonBar = UIView()
    // This needs to be false since we are using auto layout constraints
    buttonBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.44, green:0.44, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)

    view.addSubview(showUsers)
    view.addSubview(buttonBar)

    // Constrain the top of the button bar to the bottom of the segmented control
    buttonBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showUsers.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
    // Constrain the button bar to the left side of the segmented control
    buttonBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showUsers.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    // Constrain the button bar to the width of the segmented control divided by the number of segments
    buttonBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showUsers.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(showUsers.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true

    showUsers.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)),  for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
}


@objc func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        print(self.showUsers.frame.width) //147.0
        print(self.showUsers.numberOfSegments) //2
        print(self.showUsers.selectedSegmentIndex)//1

        //let originX = (self.showUsers.frame.width / CGFloat(self.showUsers.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.showUsers.selectedSegmentIndex + 1)

        let originX = (self.showUsers.frame.width / CGFloat(self.showUsers.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.showUsers.selectedSegmentIndex + 1)
        self.buttonBar.frame.origin.x = originX
    }
}
```

**Update:**
update the calculation function and it moves the line but not where I want 
[image]
[image: the bar x postion after click]

Comment: I don't see any constraints about showUsers with view. Could you show me it?

Comment: let originX = (self.showUsers.frame.width / CGFloat(self.showUsers.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.showUsers.selectedSegmentIndex + 1)

Comment: it worked but I have a glitch in the calculation I will update the post with images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are applying 'frame' changes on the view that has constraints, so try to use constraints in the method `segmentedControlValueChanged` instead of this

```
let originX = (self.showUsers.frame.width / CGFloat(self.showUsers.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.showUsers.selectedSegmentIndex + 1)
self.buttonBar.frame.origin.x = originX
```